# Value from list of string is adding sqaure brackets to the value

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-cloudwatch, terraform-provider-aws

I am creating dashboard for ecs but loadbalancer name is getting [] in "[ "mis-app-cluster" ]" because of list of string type in variable.

Is there any by which we can remove [] from the value.

List of string is mandatory.

data -

```
 {
     my-dashboard-name = "MIS-Dev-Cloudwatch-Dashboard-ECS"
     aws-region        = "eu-west-1"
     targets           = ["mis-app-cluster"]
     metrics           = ["CPUUtilization", "MemoryUtilization"]
     service_name      =   ["mis-fileserver", "mis-nginx", "mis-odi", "mis-oraclebi", "mis-ords", "mis-restdataservices"]
     aws-namespace     = "AWS/ECS"
     dim               = "ClusterName"
     stat              = "Average"
     period            = 300
   }
```

module (I have only added for ALB module below)

```
locals {

  widget-def-alb = [for metric in var.metrics :
    {
      type   = "metric",
      x      = 0,
      y      = 0
      width  = 18,
      height = 8,
      properties = {
        metrics = [for targetgroup in var.target_groups : [var.aws-namespace, metric,"TargetGroup", targetgroup, var.dim, var.targets]],
        title = "${var.aws-namespace}: ${metric}",
        region  = var.aws-region,
        period  = var.period,
        stat    = var.stat,
        view    = "timeSeries",
        legend = {
          position = "right"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}

resource "aws_cloudwatch_dashboard" "cw-dashboard-alb" {
  count = var.aws-namespace == "AWS/ApplicationELB" ? 1 : 0
  dashboard_name = var.dashboard-name

  dashboard_body = jsonencode({
    start   = "-PT9H"
    widgets = local.widget-def-alb
  })
}
```

Code -

```
module "create-dashboard" {
  source         = "../"
  for_each       = { for service in local.dashboards : service.my-dashboard-name => service if length(regexall(".*ALB.*", service.my-dashboard-name))
 > 0 }
  dashboard-name = each.value.my-dashboard-name
  aws-region     = each.value.aws-region
  targets        = each.value.targets
  metrics        = each.value.metrics
  aws-namespace  = each.value.aws-namespace
  dim            = each.value.dim
  target_groups  = each.value.target_groups
  stat           = each.value.stat
  period         = each.value.period
}
```

output

```
{
    "legend": {
        "position": "right"
    },
    "metrics": [
        [ "AWS/ECS", "CPUUtilization", "ServiceName", "mis-fileserver", "ClusterName", [ "mis-app-cluster" ] ],
        [ ".", "MemoryUtilization", ".", ".", ".", [ "mis-app-cluster" ] ]
    ],
    "period": 300,
    "region": "eu-west-1",
    "stat": "Average",
    "title": "mis-fileserver",
    "view": "timeSeries",
    "timezone": "UTC"
}
```

Comment: Sadly your question is not clear. What is generating your `output` exactly? Which line exactly causes the issue?

Comment: output is creating cloudwatch dashboard widget in aws console and values of all variables are given in code section. everything is appearing correct in widget, it just that sqaure bracket is causing the issue, if i remove them manually i am able to see the graph in dashboard. but not sure how can i remove those brackets from terraform.

Comment: So the part you call "data" is actually a value for the metrics variable?